# Android : Overcome (Stop) the reloading data always...the big headache

Tags: android, performance

I am Using TabGroupActivity for my project.. In Tab1, i moving from A1 -> A2 and when returning back the data in A1 is reloading again... the samething happening in all places.. Is there any way to overcome this.? whether i have to save instance of A1 before going to A2 . how to do this.? Please suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TabGroupActivity uses Activity Group to manage activities on a tab, and have a list of activities in a stack, on activity change it creates a view from activity exist in stack in case of back button, or new activity in case of new activity, so its not possible by activity group implementation, and ActivityGroup is also depreciated, so I would recommend to use Fragments instead of activity group, fragment can maintain backstack also.